# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'match'

Tags: python, regex, django, validation

i am using the re library to validate phone numbers by regular expression and i have used the same exact code before on other project and it was working well, but now i get

**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'match'**

models.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import re

def validate_phone(value): #the validation regex here to be used in models later
    if re.match('^(010|011|012)[0-9]{8}',value) is None :
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not a valid number' % value)
    if UserProfile.objects.filter(phone_number=value).count() > 1:
        raise ValidationError("Phone number already exists")

class UserProfile(User):
    #.... some other attributes
    mobile_number = models.CharField(validators=[validate_phone],null=True, blank=True, unique=True,max_length=16)
```

and when I try to change the mobile number from the admin to test I get this error:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  366.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  209.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1035.             if form.is_valid():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  124.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  115.             self.full_clean()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  272.         self._post_clean()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  326.             self.instance.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in clean_fields
  844.                 setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in clean
  201.         self.run_validators(value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in run_validators
  154.                 v(value)
File "/Users/fadykamal/Work/Projects/Django/ShoghlanahProject/shoghlanah/models.py" in validate_phone
  23.     if re.match('^(010|011|012)[0-9]{8}',value) is None :

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/shoghlanah/userprofile/2/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'match'
```

Comment: You must've set `re = None` somewhere. Since you didn't include your full code, we cannot see where.

Comment: Yes, what @MartijnPieters said is correct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no i didn't here is the whole code http://pastie.org/5495756

Comment: And the full traceback for your error is?

Comment: Also, other modules can do the same (`import yourmodule; yourmodule.re = None`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have searched the whole project and nothing was found the trace back is here http://pastie.org/5495843

Comment: Since nothing in the code you posted indicates any reason that the `re` module should be replaced with `None`, the only thing I can think of is that some other unseen code elsewhere in your project is messing with the import system and actually causing `re` to import correctly.

Comment: *Something* is setting `re` to `None`. It could even be something that messes with `sys.modules`. Setting `sys.modules['re'] = None` would do this too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i've searched for anything that sets the re to none and found nothing, is there anything else. it's a little hard to debug :/

Comment: @Iguananaut i am using south, tagging , tweepy these are some of the apps i use, but i don't know if they're messing with something

Comment: @FadyKamal The only thing I can suggest to you at this point is that you should try setting up a clean virtualenv with no other packages installed in it. Run your code in that with just the bare minimum you need to get it to work, and then install additional packages one at a time until you see what's breaking things. I think there's a problem with your overall Python installation.  You can get and read about virtualenv here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv